# Modify a script at runtime

Tags: unity, c#, metaprogramming

I am about to make a programming game for children, hence I will use blocks  (like Scratch or Stencyl). My question is: Is there a way that you can modify a script (let's say, by adding a string attached to a code block)?

Also, could there by a way to delete just some text for that script (for when I want to "reset" the script to its default state)?

Answer (score 3):

Unity compiles all its scripts to bytecode at build time. While there may be relatively exotic ways to JIT arbitrary source code at runtime on some platforms, it's **very likely not the cleanest or safest route to what you're looking for**.

What you can do instead is use Unity scripting to build a [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine), which then [interprets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)) the scripts that the player has authored.

There are lots of ways you could do this.

A conventional approach would be to implement this as a **text parser**, which reads a string containing the program the player has authored, turns it into a [syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), then walks the tree executing the appropriate actions at each step.

You could also try a more **distributed/modular approach**. If you want a visual block structure like Scratch or Stencyl, then you very likely have a GameObject for each command block in the player's program, just to provide its visual representation. You could attach to each such GameObject a script that inherits from a common base class or implements an "ICommandBlock" interface, exposing:

- A `SetNextCommand()` method that you can use to link commands in a chain when the player connects them. If commands can be nested, you might need a few flavours of this, like `SetChildCommand()`
- A `Resume()` method implemented for blocks that can contain other blocks, so it can continue its work once its contained statements finish (eg. a loop block would increment its loop counter, check if the loop is complete, then re-run its contained statements)
- A `Run()` method that executes the logic of this command (which might include pushing itself onto the stack and running a child command), then runs the next command set above if there is one, or resumes the last command in the stack otherwise, signalling the end of the program if the stack is empty

In this model, you and the player are effectively working at the syntax tree level itself, rather than in raw text, although the two approaches could by hybridized. You could have a text parser whose job is to spawn & wire up GameObjects corresponding to the syntax of code as the player types, for example.

Either way, you'll likely want to set this up so the running of the program occurs in discrete stages (eg. rather than calling the `nextCommand.Run()` directly, we *schedule* it to be executed after a given delay), so that you can step through the program slowly to show it working, pause or abort execution where you want, and prevent your game from locking up if the player creates an infinite loop in their code. ;)